# How to create for loop to create string search flag columns based on list of terms, then combine into one column

Tags: python, pandas

Kind of a weird roundabout issue, but basically I want to create some kind of for loop that will create "flag" columns (t/f) based on if a certain text column contains a string. There would be multiple string searches in a list like so:

```
strings = ['Cat','Dog','Hamster']`
```

I was hoping to create a new column for each one (ie search for cat, then search for dog, then search for hamster, all on the same text column, and create a flag column for each).

I was then hoping to create a separate column that combined all three, meaning if all three were true, then that cell would be Cat, Dog, Hamster. If only dog and cat were true, that cell would be Cat, Dog, and so on.

So visualized:

| Text Column | Cat | Dog | Hamster | Combined |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| the cat and dog ate the hamster | T | T | T | Cat, Dog, Hamster |
| the cat ate the hamster | T | F | T | Cat, Hamster |
| the dog ate the hamster | F | T | T | Dog, Hamster |
| the hamster ate his dinner | F | F | T | Hamster |

This text search would not be case sensitive, previously I had been manually doing this search via this code:

```
df1x = df1x.assign(String= (df1["Text Column"].str.contains(string, case = False, regex = True)))
```

Thank you for any help you can provide me, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only wanted the combined column you could use something like this.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

df["Combined"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: ','.join ([
        animal
        for animal in ["cat", "dog", "hamster"]
        if animal.upper() in row['Text Column'].upper()
        ]), axis = 1
)

print(df)
```

|  | Text Column | Combined |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | the cat and dog ate the hamster | cat,dog,hamster |
| 1 | the cat ate the hamster | cat,hamster |
| 2 | the dog ate the hamster | dog,hamster |
| 3 | the hamster ate his dinner | hamster |

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a for-loop that would go through the list. Inside the for-loop would iterate through the search terms using another for-loop. Then write an if-statement either add on true or false to the column depending on if the text word is equal to the search word. If it’s true( the term matches) you could just use += to add the search term that’s currently being iterated onto the column.